# Why Apache IoTDB reported "Invalid method name" error after startup?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

executeQueryStatement failed: org.apache.iotdb.rpc.IoTDBConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'executeQueryStatementV2'，1.0版本的

I found an error right after I start up and tried to query using Apache IoTDB Version 1.0: "executeQueryStatement failed: org.apache.iotdb.rpc.IoTDBConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'executeQueryStatementV2' ". Anyone know why this error occurs?

does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message looks like you have already updated to Version 1.0 of Apache IoTDB, but the 1.0 client has accessed lower version of IoTDB, therefore the startup process went wrong and you cannot use the method in Version 1.0.

Try to check if any sub-client or any other nodes have not updated to Version 1.0 yet, and update them all to see if this error occurs again.